# VideoView doesn't display from raspberry pi video streaming in android app

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I am using motion server in a Raspberry pi.  I am getting a video stream in a laptop through the browser using address `192.168.16.5:8081`, it works fine.  I want to get this video stream in an android device.  I wanted to use `VideoView` to display it, there are no obvious errors and the VideoStream window does not play.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String path="http://192.168.43.49:8081";

        VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        video.setVideoPath(path);
        video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The VideoView works through the browser, but not through the Android App.  Any clues on what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your manifest?

Comment: Yes I did. @user3819356

Comment: Try to `Uri.parse(path)` and then `setVideoURI(uriPath)`

Comment: I tried but no effect :-(

Comment: Can we play video streaming in media Player? @user3819356

Comment: Did you try to display the static video file from any website?

Comment: But through mobile browser.. I am getting video streaming... Not from my own app :-(

Comment: Try to display the static video file from any website to check either it is URL problem, or it is `VideoView` init problem.

Comment: It is not working too. tell me any link of static video?? may be format problem @user3819356

Comment: http://www.gostream.nl/play.stream.haber7.php?id=362767811&w=620&h=540
I have tried this one..  "Cant play this video"

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp from [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/) example